# Is this R code of Rao score test for the Bernoulli data model correct?

Tags: r, statistics, bernoulli-probability

I am a complete statistical noob and new to R, hence the question. I've tried to find an implementation of the [Rao score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_test) for the particular case when one's `data` is binary and each observation has bernoulli distribution. I stumbled upon `anova` in the R language but failed to understand how to use that. Therefore, I tried implementing Rao score for this particular case myself:

```
rao.score.bern <- function(data, p0) {
  # assume `data` is a list of 0s and 1s
  y <- sum(data)
  n <- length(data)
  phat <- y / n

  z <- (phat - p0) / sqrt(p0 * (1 - p0) / n)
  p.value <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(z)))
}
```

I am pretty sure that there is a bug in my code because it produces only two distinct p-values in the following scenario:

```
p0 <- 1 / 4
p <- seq(from=0.01, to=0.5, by=0.01)
n <- seq(from=5, to=70, by=1)
g <- expand.grid(n, p)

data <- apply(g, 1, function(x) rbinom(x[1], 1, x[2]))
p.values <- sapply(data, function(x) rao.score.bern(x[[1]], p0))
```

Could someone please show me where the problem is? Could you perhaps point me to a built-in solution in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First test, then debug.**

### Test

Does `rao.score.bern` work at all?

> rao.score.bern(c(0,0,0,1,1,1), 1/6))

This returns...nothing!  Fix it by replacing the ultimate line by

```
2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(z)))
```

This eliminates the unnecessary assignment.

> rao.score.bern(c(0,0,0,1,1,1), 1/6))

```
[1] 0.02845974
```

OK, now we're getting somewhere.

### Debug

Unfortunately, the code still doesn't work.  Let's debug by yanking the call to `rao.score.bern` and replacing it by something that shows us the input.  Don't apply it to the large input you created!  Use a small piece of it:

> sapply(data[1:5], function(x) x[[1]])

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

That's not what you expected, is it?  It's returning just one zero for each element of `data`.  What about this?

> sapply(data[1:5], function(x) x)

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 
...
[[5]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Much better!  The variable `x` in the call to `sapply` refers to the entire vector, which is what you want to pass to your routine.  Whence

> p.values <- sapply(data, function(x) rao.score.bern(x, p0)); hist(p.values)

[image: Figure]

Comment: This is a great answer, explaining a strategy for identifying the problems, rather than just pointing out what the present problems are.